# Georeference a LAS file with txt2las using a Geomedia coordinate system file (.csf)

Tags: coordinate-system, csv, las, format, lastools

I need to transform a file in a .csv file into a LAS file. I have a LiDAR data folder, in this folder I have these files:

1. A .csv file that contains the the point data
2. Some metadata files (schema, HTML, MTD, SGML)
3. A .csf file that is *"An Intergraph Geomedia coordinate system file"*.

I am using `txt2las` to change the format but when I do this the LAS file does not have any reference, when I upload the new las file to ArcMap it says that is georeference system is unknown.

```
txt2las file.cvs -o file.las
```

I assume that the information about the geographic information is in the .csf but I don't know how to link it to the `txt2las` function.

Is there any way command `txt2las` to set a CRS from a `.csf` input? Or any other way to assign a CRS to the LAS file?

Comment: Are you able to read the content of the csf file? If yes what does it contain? If no do you have an idea of the expected coordinate reference system for your dataset?

Comment: No, I cannot open the csf file, I'm trying to open it with ArcMap, but honestly I don't know hoe to open it. And yes, I know my coordinate system, it is specified in the metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `csf` file if you know your projection. You can set the CRS using the appropriated command

```
txt2las file.csv -o file.las -epsg 32754
```

The following is also valid

```
txt2las file.csv -o file.las -utm 17T
```

Check out the documentation of [txt2las](http://lastools.org/download/txt2las_README.txt) and [las2las](http://lastools.org/download/las2las_README.txt)

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing that but it says: ERROR: unknown argument '-epsg', and when I do it with -utm it has the same error unknown argument '-utm'. Maybe I need to install something else?

Comment: Are you using `LAStools` or `liblas`?

Comment: I'm using `liblas` . I can install that package in Ubuntu but I'm not able to install LAStools package

Comment: I installed `LAStools` and it worked perfectly. Thanks! I still don´t understand why does not work with `liblas` ...

Comment: Because it is not the same software